# processes came into halt and new started process halt as well

Tags: tmux, deadlock

It seems that all my processes has been halted for ~ 4 hours at the time of the screenshot below, since I was running several machine learning experiments with tmux, and I found there has been no output to stdout anymore since 4 hours.  I try to start a new experiment, but as well there is no output to stdout although i can find the new process with htop. Besides, I can not stop the new experiment with control+C, i can only kill it in htop, and from stdout i confirm it is also killed.

I also discovered this seems to be caused by the tool python invoke,

http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/stable/

since if I do not use invoke to start an experiment with `inv debug`, but simply use

```
python main.py --debug
```

The new process can be started, although it also get halted in between.

Any clue what have happened and are there any ways to avoid or reduce this?  Thanks!

[image]

system info:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

python

```
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 19:59:22)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import invoke
>>> invoke.__version__
'1.5.0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that simply killing some processes will renew the long halted remaining tasks.